# Как логгировать имя шаблона golang

Tags: golang

Всем привет
Есть функция которая показывает пользователю html шаблон

```
func TemplateGetting(w http.ResponseWriter, templatePath string, mess interface{}) {
    templWelcome, _ := template.ParseFiles("../static/" + templatePath)
    user := ForHTML{
        Message: mess,
    }
    templWelcome.Execute(w, user)
}
```

Так же есть middleware который ведет лог и находится в отдельном пакете.

```
package logging

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type ForHTML struct {
    Message interface{}
}

type loggingResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    statusCode int
    statusText string
}


/* _____________________________________________Logging Starts_____________________________________________________ */
/* Capturing status codes*/
func Logging(wrappedHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    dt := time.Now()
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        checkIfStatusOK := NewLoggingResponseWriter(w)
        wrappedHandler.ServeHTTP(checkIfStatusOK, r)
        statusCode := checkIfStatusOK.statusCode
        ip, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
        logrus.Info(dt.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05 from "),
            ip, " --> ", r.Host, r.URL.Path, "\t(", r.Method, ")\t")
        logrus.Info(dt.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05 from "),
            r.Host, r.URL.Path, " --> ", ip, "\t\t", statusCode, http.StatusText(statusCode)) //Вот здесь чтобы выводилось имя шалона
        fmt.Println()
    })
}

func NewLoggingResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter) *loggingResponseWriter {
    return &loggingResponseWriter{w, http.StatusOK, http.StatusText(http.StatusOK)}
}

func (loggintStructItem *loggingResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    loggintStructItem.statusCode = code
    loggintStructItem.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы внутри функции Logging выводилось еще и имя шаблона. Например index.html.
Можно ли реализовать отлов имени шаблона например из ResponseWriter-а и вывода на экран.

Понятно что можно просто внутри TemplateGetting вывод сделать но тогда это будет отдельная строка лога, но хочется чтобы именно в общем middleware было и выводилось внутри этой же строки.

Comment: Что вы называете *имя шаблона* - путь в файловой системе? После `template.ParseFiles` этот путь безвозвратно потерян. Вам нужно куда-то сохранять его.

Comment: @PakUula Как считаете, мое решение с глобальной переменной(мой ответ на этот вопрос) норм или лучше еще подумать, чтобы не юзать глобальные переменные?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как нашел решение.
Использовать глобальную переменную в пакете logging.
Вот так выглядит теперь функция показа шаблона

```
var templatePath string

func TemplateGetting(w http.ResponseWriter, templName string, mess interface{}) {
    templWelcome, _ := template.ParseFiles("../static/" + templName)
    templatePath = templName
    user := ForHTML{
        Message: mess,
    }
    templWelcome.Execute(w, user)
}
```

`templatePath` можно в любом месте лога вывести)
Если есть решение получше то хотел бы все же узнать.

Comment: Напишите свой тип `LoggableTemplate`, в котором метод `template.ParseFiles` сохраняет путь, а метод `template.Execute` пишет в лог. Но мне кажется, проще писать это имя в лог в вашей функции `TemplateGetting`